# Java application server for Windows

Tags: windows, java, application-server

I'm currently setting up operational environment for our company, which includes installing Crowd for SSO, JIRA for bug tracking, and Confluence as our wiki. My idea is that all these products should be available via HTTP 80 on our internal development server (kinda `http://dev/crowd`, `http://dev/jira`, etc.) and will be available from the outside (for instance, Google Apps requires publicly available SSO server, so `http://dev.acme.com/crowd` should work there).

I'm currently at a loss trying to choose good appserver for all these products. What I need is a Windows Server 2008 x64 R2-compatible appserver which is easy enough to set up and administer (GUI administration utilities will be nice, but I'm quite comfortable with console and configuration files) and wich can handle some 5+ applications for a 10+ people organization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just been through this process (literally in the last week) with JIRA+Crowd+Confluence on a WinXP box. (not a 64-bit server OS but probably very similar)

It's not hard to set up Apache + the appropriate proxy info so from the outside you are accessing these via HTTP 80, but internally they run on Tomcat 8080 (or whatever your tomcat port is).

For most of Atlassian's features the install documentation is very good (I had a painful experience with installing the Apache::CrowdAuth connector, otherwise all has run smoothly). I'd suggest you look at their [Apache+JIRA integration page](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/v3.13/apacheintegration.html) for example.

Comment: Thanks, but no. Tomcat is well over my head. Plus, I'm planning to use Apache to only manage SVN repository, nothing more (yes, this might seem stupid, but Crowd requires Apache to work).

Comment: Tomcat is pretty easy! I'm not even a real sysadmin, just a HW/SW developer experimenting around. If I can figure it out, you can too.

Comment: I'm not a sysadmin either, but I _really_ don't want to dig through piles of XML that Tomcat configuration is.

Comment: Tomcat can be a pain in the butt, no doubt, but the XML configurations that comes with it is intrinsic to JSP...If you're looking to deploy some JSP apps, you're going to need to dig in it, at least a little bit.

Comment: Atlassian apps aren't JSP (as far as I know), but they are .war files.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a solution with all web-based administration, consider the [Sun Java Web Server](http://www.sun.com/software/products/web_srvr/index.xml). It does the same job as Apache+Tomcat, including many advanced features such as WebDAV access and virtual servers. There are both free and commercial support options.

I don't have a lot of personal experience with the platform but I have heard good things about it's ease of use for non-admins

Answer (score 1):

I setup Jira and Confluence on a windows machine some time ago. I used IIS as the basic web server and used ajp_iis to redirect specific URLs to the tomcat instances running on different ports. Works pretty well and was easy enough to set up.

Answer (score 1):

JBoss is supposed to be able to run on any platform.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Jason S. Since, the Java-based application is doesn't include any EJB (enterprise Java beans) you can live without an application server like JBoss or  WebSphere. All you need is a Web Container (Tomcat). In order for Apache to process Java request you need to compile Apache with mod_jk. Apache does not handle Java request out-of-the-box. All this stuff is pretty straightforward on *nix O/S.

Also, keep in mind Tomcat is a Web Container and not a Web Server. If you use JBoss, the front end that you use to connect to with your browser is actually stripped-down version of Tomcat- web container. Web Container isn't build to handle heavy requests. So, for production systems, you should always have load balanced web servers talking to tomcat/jboss instances.